# Missing chapter name when using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I want to get the following header:

Left page: `\thepage\hfill\chaptername{}\thechapter`

Right page: `\chaptername\hfill\thepage`

So I write:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec} % enagles loading of OpenType fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text} % without this XeLaTeX won't turn "--" into dashes
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setromanfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\thechapter}
\fancyhead[RE]{\chaptername}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

Foo!

\chapter{bar}

Bar!

\chapter{baz}

Baz!

\end{document}
```

but it doesn't print chapter name in header. What do I do wrong?

**Edit**:

Current best bet:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec} % enagles loading of OpenType fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text} % without this XeLaTeX won't turn "--" into dashes
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setromanfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand{\rightmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\leftmark}[1]{\chaptername{}\thechapter}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

Foo!

\chapter{bar}

Bar!

\chapter{baz}

Baz!

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\chaptername` doesn't refer to the chapter title, it produces the word "Chapter" (possibly translated). You probably want `\leftmark`, instead.

Comment: I guess it should be `\fancyhead[RE]{\thechapter}` and `\fancyhead[LO]{\chaptername}`, no ?

Comment: Nope. Only `\thepage`. I know there are subtleties like `\chaptermark` and \rightmark` -- but I though it should be working this crude way also.

Comment: @egreg: `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}` with `\fancyhead[RE]{\chaptermark}` doesn't work either.

Comment: @Corentin: I'll fix it.

Comment: What I mean is that as far as I understand, whatever you write in the first two `\fancyhead` is overridden by the last one, which only uses `\thepage`.

Comment: @Adobe You *don't* want `\chaptermark` in the argument to `\fancyhead`, but `\leftmark`.

Comment: @Corentin: You right. But `\fancyhead[LO]{\thechapter}
\fancyhead[RE]{\chaptermark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}` also doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I think the second problem is the one egreg raised.

Comment: @egreg: I just tried `\renewcommand{\rightmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\leftmark}[1]{\chaptername \thechapter}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}` -- doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does what you specify:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec} % enables loading of OpenType fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for mock text in the example

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Ligatures=TeX} % without this XeLaTeX won't turn "--" into dashes
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\chaptername~\thechapter}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\kant

\chapter{bar}

\kant

\end{document}
```

Note that `\pagestyle{fancy}` must go *before* the redefinitions of the headers and of `\chaptermark`. The current chapter title is available as `\leftmark` which *mustn't* be redefined.

Comment: Cool. I find that sometimes that order thing is a little bit unclear. How do I know that `fancyhf{}` redefines `chaptermark` for example.

Comment: @Adobe There's plenty of examples in the documentation of `fancyhdr`. It's `\pagestyle{fancy}` that does the redefinition, by the way. Last, I repeat: *don't* use `\setromanfont`.

Comment: Ok: `\setdefaultlanguage` is deprecated in favour of `\setmainlanguage`, and `\setromanfont` is deprecated in favour of `\setmainfont`.